# Phonegap simple javascript not running (onClick issue?) - Both Android and iOS

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

This seems to work fine when I test in firefox. As soon as I install it through phonegap, it doesn't. I have removed as much code as I can to make it as simple as I can.

Why when I press the button, does the alert('ok'); not happen on iOS or Android?

My code is below.

Thanks,

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>XYZ</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http:code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http:code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http:code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    function saveResponseToLocalStorage(){
        alert('ok');
    }
    </script>


    </head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>XYZ</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content">   
        <h2>Search By Postcode + Name</h2>  
        <form>
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="text" id="text" value="">
            <br/>
            <label for="city">Post Code:</label>
            <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" value="">
            <br/>
            <button onclick="saveResponseToLocalStorage()">Search</button>  
        </form>
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't you have to include the cordova/phonegap js, and wait for the device ready event?

Comment: You're missing the // after http: for all of your script sources. Also, you may want to upgrade your versions of jQuery and jQuery Mobile. But I tested your code on a PhoneGap build on my end and it worked perfectly fine, even without the phonegap.js included. What version of PhoneGap are you using?

Comment: I'm using phonegap build, I was under the impression it would build with the latest? Well spotted with the missing //'s.

Comment: @Andrew Lively, please can I ask which version of Android or iOS you were using to test with after using PhoneGap build?

Comment: On iOS I was using 6.1 and Android I was using 4.2

Comment: Thanks, still doesn't seem to be working for me. No idea why :(.

Comment: Sorry ubunfu, I gave up in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this before the alert

```
navigator.notification.alert("ok");
```